# vertical-align: middle issues

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Can anyone tell why this doesn't work? http://www.webdevout.net/test?01x afaik it should; my `<div>` elements should all be block-level so anything in `#container > div` should be in the middle of the `#container` div (with the orange outline), right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The style `vertical-align` only applies to table cells, images and span tags.

Comment: which means my container needs to be a fixed width (http://www.webdevout.net/test?0g) for this to work with `table-cell`, right?

Comment: @Guffa, that's wrong. According to [CSS2 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height): *Applies to: inline-level and 'table-cell' elements*

Comment: @feklee: And what are table cells, images and span tags?

Comment: @Guffa, there are more inline elements than images and spans, but you write "only". To quote the [CSS2 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) again: *The following values of the 'display' property make an element inline-level: 'inline', 'inline-table', and 'inline-block'.*

Answer (score 1):

use `display: table` on your container and then you can use `vertical-align` on your inner `display: inline-block` elements.

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/uzcrt/